# show that any continuous function can be approximated uniformly

Tags: functions, approximation

[image]

I do not know where to start because i have not dealt with a question like this before. I feel that i have to use the Stone-Weierstrass theorem, but im not sure how to use it.

Comment: If you already have Stone-Weierstraß at your disposal, just verify that the set of polynomials without constant term satisfies the premises of the theorem. $\epsilon > 0$ is essential, of course.

Comment: So, i need to show that the set of polynomials without constant term separates points on [epsilon, 1] and vanishes at no point of [epsilon, 1] , so that the uniform closures of the set of polynomials without the constant term is C([epsilon,1]). I hope that makes some sense

Comment: Yes, that's what you need to show (stating that they form a subalgebra of $C([\epsilon,1])$ won't hurt).

Comment: Ok, so by definition if the set of polynomials on [epsilon,1] is said to seperate points if for every pit of distinct points x1 not= x2 there exists a function f belonging to the set of polynomials with f(x1) not= f(x2), so can i take the function x^2, because for all x1 not= x2 we have that f(x1) = x1^2 = x2^2 = f(x2)

and for the vanish at no point condition can't i use the same function  because we have that e not= 0 so x^2 f(x) = x^2 >0 for all x belonging to [epsilon, 1]

Comment: You could also take $x$, every monomial $x^k$ works (and a lot of others too).

Comment: So, i would say that since the function f(x) = x separates all points and and vanishes at no point of [epsilon,1] we have that the above holds and so the set of polynomials without the constant term is C([epsilon,1]) and that would be enough.

Comment: Not "is $C([\epsilon,1])$". The algebra of the polynomials without constant terms is dense in $C([\epsilon,1])$.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, where we say for A subset B, to say A is dense in B is to say B subset cl(A)?

Comment: Yes, that's the definition. And here it means every function can be uniformly approximated.

Comment: Thanks alot, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the function $g(x) = f(x)/x$. By Stone-Weierstrass you know that there exists a sequence of polynomials $p_k(x)$ uniformly approximating $g(x)$ on $[\epsilon,1]$. To prove that the sequence $q_k(x) = x\cdot p_k(x)$ uniformly approximates $f$ just notice that
$$
|q_k(x) - f(x)| = |x\cdot p_k(x) - f(x)| = |x|\cdot|p_k(x) - g(x)| \le |p_k(x)-g(x)| \to 0
$$

Comment: Also nice. (Note: polynomials with a "y" in English.)

Comment: corrected thanks! :-)